# How to render HTML templates in Pedestal?

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I am going over the Pedestal docs at

```
https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/tree/master/guides/documentation
```

There are no examples for how to render html from templates. Does pedestal even have this functionality? If so, can anyone please explain how this works, with an example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Pedestal`  doesn't ship with a template system, but instead relies on third-party libraries. You could check this [`template-server`](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/tree/master/samples/template-server)example.

It demonstrates the use of several popular templating libraries :

- [hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup)
- [enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive)
- [mustache](https://web.archive.org/web/20130305104813/http://mustache.github.com:80/)
- [stringtemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [comb](https://github.com/weavejester/comb)
- [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer)

But you could use any templating library you want.

[Here](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/03/choosing-a-templating-language-in-clojure.html) is an article to help choose one.